# Reference another F# Jupyter Notebook

Tags: f#, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to reference functions from another [F# Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/fsprojects/IfSharp)?
I see number of answers for doing the same in Python Notebooks, but can't seem to find a way to do the same in F# Notebooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a hack. You put the code you want to reference in a .fsx file inside a module:

```
//myScript.fsx
module Script1
    let myFunction x y = x + 2 * y
```

Then you can simply reference that a .fsx file in your current jupyter notebook:

```
#load "myScript.fsx" 
open Script1    
printfn "%i" (myFunction 8 9)
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. I figures how to reference my own compiled assemblies so that works for me for now. 
`#r "../RELATIVE_PATH/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/YOUR_PROJECT.dll"`

Comment: +1. I do this very regularly with code that will be shared between notebooks. It is generally more convenient than referencing a compiled assembly if you are going to be making regular changes to the module.

Comment: Just tried that. It is actually way better cause you do not need to close the notebook to recompile the assembly. Thanks a lot!